# Rails Devise redirect after signup

Tags: ruby-on-rails, devise, devise-confirmable

I have rails app that uses Devise with confirmable by email. Emails are send thru gmail. When user fill registration form then is redirected to "/user", but this path doesn't exists hence app crashes. Is there anything that I can do, to force redirect after submit to index? 
Yes I've already tried [Devise Wiki](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)://)
thanks

Answer (score 3):

Before you ask such questions please take some time and search for the solution by yourself.

It took me 30 seconds to find the [Solution on a Wiki page](https://github.com/plataformatec/devise/wiki/How-To:-Redirect-to-a-specific-page-on-successful-sign-up-(registration)) of Devise.

Just create a `RegistrationsController` which inherits from `Devise::RegistrationsController` and add a `#after_sign_up_path_for` method to it.

Then just add `devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }` to your routes if you have `users` as resource.

Comment: If everyone who could research did so, 90% of folks would be out of jobs :) Sometimes it's the convenience / assurance people need

Comment: `@Skodik.o` can you explain what results you've seen? You mention it didn't work; what happened?

Comment: I have registrations_controller.rb with defined method for after_sign_up_path_for and even method for after_inactive_sign_up_path_for, both should return index - 'posts#index'. When user finishes registration then instead of redirecting to index it redirects to /users

Comment: Have you also added the `controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }` to your routes?

Comment: Yes, my routes looks like this: devise_for :users, controllers: { registrations: "registrations" }

Comment: 2022: I ran into the same problem. However, given I was requiring users to confirm, they were registered as Inactive. Thus, I had to use `after_inactive_sign_up_path_for` instead.